# Install Django on Mac by copying to directory?

Tags: python, django, macos, terminal, psycopg2

I'm kind of confused where I should have installed Django 1.3.1 on my Mac. I moved the Django 1.3.1 folder to Documents, and then opens terminal, cd Documents/Django-1.3.1 setup.py install. Now, i'm having all sorts of problems after trying to install psycopg2.

How can i uninstall and remove django, so that i can install it again cleanly. And, is it possible to paste the django folder into the directory it should be in?

I'm a beginner with Django and using terminal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should use [pip](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) or [easy_install](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) for installing any python libraries.

easy_install is already available with python, so for installing django you do 
`easy_install django` from the terminal.

pip is a replacement for easy_install for installing pip you do `easy_install pip` now pip is installed, for installing django via pip you do 
`pip install django`

Comment: I've tried that, and i get this message: `code  Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): django in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages ` 

But when i'm creating a django project, i have to create it from the Documents/Django-1.3.1 directory. This gives me an error when i try to runserver 8000. The error is: `codeImportError: No module named django.core.management`.

Comment: @Adnan django is already installed, what is Django-1.3.1 in Documents?

Comment: Either ways it is already installed, what do you want to do next? For creating a new django project you do django-admin.py startproject mysite from the terminal and follow this tutorial https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/intro/tutorial01/

Comment: I see now. So, now that i created a project. Why do i get the error `code ImportError: No module named django.core.management `  when i type ./manage.py runserver 8000. Also, I changed the permission of ./manage.py using `code chmod +x ./manage.py` . Is that alright?

Comment: Probably django is not in your PYTHONPATH.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4593/discussion-between-vishal-and-adnan)